# tty default fops and driver specific fops

Tags: linux-device-driver

I was just going to one of the code in Linux kernel for UART. I was able to link most of the things except the one which is described in here.

In file "tty_io.c" and function "tty_cdev_add" we can clearly see that

```
driver->cdevs[index]->ops = &tty_fops;
```

Where "tty_fops" is the default tty fops.

But somehwere in the mian driver code "tty_set_operations" is getting called which will set the "ttydriver->ops = driver_fops".

I know that when the open will gets called basically, the open from cdev should get called. But I am unable to find where the cdev_open which is is default tty operation open is mapped to driver specific calls.

Comment: `tty_set_operations` sets TTY operations, not file operations.

Comment: `ttydriver->ops` gets copied into `tty->ops` at some point by `alloc_tty_struct` and `tty_open` (`tty_fops.open`) calls `tty->ops->open`, which is your TTY driver-specific open.